# gganimate map, transition by quarter

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, gganimate

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
```

I am trying to build a map that animates the BLS quarterly employment data with transitions that happen by quarter. I have joined the employment data, selected for the third month of employment with map data from urmanmapr. It has already been filted down to the private sector's own code. Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

[image]

Here's the code that makes a static map for the most recent quater:

```
warefull3 %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = month3_emplvl))+ 
  geom_polygon(color = NA) +
  geom_polygon(data = states, mapping = aes(long, lat, group = group),
               fill = NA, color = "#ffffff")+
  coord_map(projection = "albers", lat0 = 39, lat1 = 45)
```

And the resulting map:
[image]

But when I add in the other dates, and try to make an animation with this code it doesn't work.

```
warefull4 %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = month3_emplvl))+ 
  geom_polygon(color = NA) +
  geom_polygon(data = states, mapping = aes(long, lat, group = group),
               fill = NA, color = "#ffffff")+
  coord_map(projection = "albers", lat0 = 39, lat1 = 45) +
  transition_states(yearqtr)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in transform_polygon(all_frames, next_state, ease, params$transition_length[i], : transformr is required to tween polygons
```

If it helps I made the yearqtr column like this:

```
wareall %>% 
  filter(own_code == 5) %>% 
  unite(yearqtr, c(year, qtr,), sep = "-", remove = FALSE) -> wareall

library(zoo)
wareall$yearqtr <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(wareall$yearqtr))
```

Any thoughts here would be appreciated.

Comment: Install the latest version of {transformr} . I.e. install.packages('transformr')

Comment: Wow. Yeah that worked.